# How to place css arrow on top of image

Tags: html, css

i need place small css arrow in top right corner of img, like this [image]

Here is my css code for arrow, but I dont know how to put it together.

```
.cssarrow {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 20px 20px 0;
    border-color: transparent blue transparent transparent;
}
```

thx for help

Answer (score 4):

First wrap the image and the arrow by a `<div>` element as follows:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/200" alt="">
    <div class="cssarrow"></div>
</div>
```

Then use absolute positioning to place the arrow on top-right corner of the wrapper div:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsbin.com/toyam/1/edit)**

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;    /* Establish a containing block for the absolute element */
  display: inline-block; /* To make width fit to the content */
}

.wrapper img {
  vertical-align: middle; /* Fix the gap under the inline level element */
}

.cssarrow {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 20px 20px 0;
  border-color: transparent gold transparent transparent;

  position: absolute; /* Remove the element from normal flow */
  top: 0; right: 0;   /* Position the element at top-right corner of the wrapper */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

possible to use pseudo-class  [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/meLrj)

```
<div class="wrap">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="">
</div>

.wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.wrap:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0;
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 30px 30px 0;
  border-color: transparent blue transparent transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. Check fiddle for example with **your image**

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jk1j6c4k/7/)**

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtYMk.jpg' />
    <div class='cssarrow'></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main {
    width:100%
}
.cssarrow {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 20px 20px 0;
    border-color: transparent blue transparent transparent;
    z-index:100;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
img {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%
}
```